# PDO MySQL fetchAll() using double the necessary memory in result?

Tags: php, pdo

When I use `->fetchAll()` with PDO, the resulting array looks like this when I do a `print_r()`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [week] => 2006-03-05
            [0] => 2006-03-05
            [ath] => 112.89166667
            [1] => 112.89166667
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [week] => 2006-03-12
            [0] => 2006-03-12
            [ath] => 260.04527778
            [1] => 260.04527778
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [week] => 2006-03-19
            [0] => 2006-03-19
            [ath] => 219.23472222
            [1] => 219.23472222
        )
```

etc., etc.

Are the resulting values stored twice in memory?  One under a numerical array index like `0` and `1`, and the other under its named index, such as `week` or `ath`?

I am mainly just curious.  I don't expect this to really impact my program significantly.  Thanks.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> Are the resulting values stored twice in memory?

Yes. See the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php):

> PDO::FETCH_BOTH (default): returns an array indexed by both column name and 0-indexed column number as returned in your result set

Use the optional `$fetch_style` parameter to change the way fetchAll() behaves.

```
$result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Ah thanks Pekka!  I hadn't understood what that parameter was.

Comment: and how to get only the 0-indexed column number array ?